# What are the best practices for creating constructors in sub-classes

Tags: java, oop

So I'm working on an assignment for class, and we need to create 3 classes: 
Person, Customer, and PreferredCustomer, which the hierarchy in that order.

In Person, I have the following constructors:

```
public Person() {
    this.name = "";
    this.address = "";
    this.phoneNumber = "";
}

public Person(String name, String address, String phoneNumber) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

In Customer:

```
public Customer(boolean isOnMailingList, int customerId) {
    this.isOnMailingList = isOnMailingList;
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
```

In Preferred Customer:

```
public PreferredCustomer(boolean isOnMailingList, int customerId, double purchaseAmount) {
    super(isOnMailingList, customerId);
    this.purchaseAmount = purchaseAmount;
    this.discountPercentage = calculateDiscountPercentage();
}
```

So my question here primarily deals with the constructors in the child classes. Should I accept parent members in the constructors of child classes like I did in PreferredCustomer, or should I use the setters when creating an instance of the object? My only concern is that the constructor for the child classes will have very long parameter lists. What are your thoughts here? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. If your parent class does not have any other constructor besides an arguments constructor, you will always have to declare a `super(...)` in your child constructor, no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to take all the parameters you need in the child's constructor, as you run the risk of a NullPointerException if you ever forget to set a field and then try to access it.

A constructor's responsibility is to produce a **valid** object that encapsulates **all** its necessary data, and therefore, if you have the information at the time of creation, then you must use it, even if the constructor signature becomes too long.

Answer (score 0):

A better way (imho) for the default constructor is to do the following:

```java
public Person() {
  this("","",""); // of course the fields could just be assigned "" too.
}
```

For constructors with long argument lists you can have static factory methods to return instances.

Finally, setters are great when you have long lists and don't want to worry about position of the arguments.  Each setter must return the object so the next setter can use it to set its own value.

Here is an example.

```java
    public class FooDemo {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Foo p1 = new Foo().setFirstName("John").setLastName("Doe");
          Foo p2 = new Foo().setLastName("Doe").setFirstName("Jane");
          System.out.println(p1);
          System.out.println(p2);
       }
    }

    class Foo {
       String firstName;
       String lastName;

       public Foo setFirstName(String fname) {
          firstName = fname;
          return this;
       }
       public Foo setLastName(String lname) {
          lastName = lname;
          return this;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return firstName + " " + lastName;
       }
    }
```